# An error occurred while trying to call Controller->createAction()

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am trying to create something with extbase, but the error-message I get is not very helpful. I took the blog_example extension as a guide. A (maybe) important difference is: I don't have a database table because I want to write a custom domain repository that connects to an external servive through REST.

The actual error message (displayed above the plugin, not as an exception message):

> An error occurred while trying to call Tx_MyExt_Controller_SubscriptionController->createAction()

---

**Classes/Controller/SubscriptionController:**
Stripped down to the important parts.

```
class Tx_MyExt_Controller_SubscriptionController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController 
{
    /**
     * @var Tx_MyExt_Domain_Repository_SubscriberRepository
     */
    protected $subscriberRepository;


    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeAction()
    {
        $this->subscriberRepository = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_MyExt_Domain_Repository_SubscriberRepository');
    }


    /**
     * @param Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Subscriber $subscriber
     * @dontvalidate $subscriber
     * @return  string      The rendered view
     */
    public function newAction(Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Subscriber $subscriber = null)
    {
            $this->view->assign('subscriber', $subscriber);
    }

    /**
     * @param Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Subscriber $subscriber
     * @return  string      The rendered view
     */
    public function createAction(Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Subscriber $subscriber)
    { }

}
```

**Classes/Domain/Model/Subscriber**

```
class Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Subscriber extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity 
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @dontvalidate
     */
    protected $email = '';



    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return void
     */
    public function setEmail($email) 
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() 
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

**Resources/Private/Templates/Subscription/new**

```
<f:form action="create" controller="Subscription" objectName="Subscriber" object="{subscriber}" method="post">
    <f:form.textfield property="email"></f:form.textfield>
    <f:form.submit value="submit"></f:form.submit>
</f:form>
```

**Facts**

- Adding `$subscriber = null` removes the message. But `$subscriber` is `null` then
- A `var_dump($this->request->getArguments());` displays the form's fields
- There is an index action, and it is also the first action defined in `ext_localconf.php`

---

The hints and solutions I found aren't working for me, so I hope someone can guide me into the right direction.

Comment: Just to verify: have you got the getter and setter in your `Subscriber` model?

Comment: yup. added setter/getter to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classic case of "start over from scratch and it works, and if you compare it you have the same code, though".

I updated the code in the question, maybe it helps someone.

Comment: yes, you just need to make sure that a corresponding TCA is present, beside valid ext_*.php files.

Answer (score 7):

I've got the same bug.

If you pass an Model as argument to an method, it will also validate the model fields.

I've had this annotation on my model property:

```
/**
 *
 * @var \string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
```

It validates the "@validate" annotation.
The field in the database was empty so i got the error message

```
An error occurred while trying to call ...
```

It would be good if there was a better error message.
You need to customize the validation annotation or verify that the property is not empty in the database

Hope it helps somebody

Comment: That's the problem I had.

Comment: This helped me too. A field was not set as required in TCA, but still had `* @validate NotEmpty` in the model. The detail view failed with `An error occurred while trying to call NAMESPACE\Myext\Controller\ItemController->listAction()`. (The reason it shows `listAction`for the detail view is that there is a forwarder from list -> detail in the controller)

Answer (score 3):

**In addtion:** check any Validations in your Model and your TCA. If a field is marked as `@validate NotEmpty` in your Model and is not marked appropriately in the TCA, a record can be saved ignoring the @validate settings in the Model. This can happen if you change the Model and/or TCA after creating records.

**An example:** 
Field 'textfield' is set to not validate, both in the TCA and the Model. You create a new record and save it without filling in the field 'textfield' (you can, it is not set to validate). You then change the Model setting 'textfield' to `@validate NotEmpty` and then try to show the record on the FE, you will get the error.

**The solution for that example:**
Simply remove the validation in your Model OR check validations in the TCA and Model so that they work together.

--

A German blog post covers this solution: http://www.constantinmedia.com/2014/04/typo3-extbase-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-call-anyaction/

Answer (score 2):

just override the template method getErrorFlashMessage in yout controller to provide a custom error message...

```
/**
 * A template method for displaying custom error flash messages, or to
 * display no flash message at all on errors. Override this to customize
 * the flash message in your action controller.
 *
 * @return string|boolean The flash message or FALSE if no flash message should be set
 * @api
 */
protected function getErrorFlashMessage() {
    return 'An error occurred while trying to call ' . get_class($this) . '->' . $this->actionMethodName . '()';
}
```

Comment: the problem isn't that I want to get rid of the flash but to get rid of the error stopping the plugin to work.